# The image does not appear if I press the button using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I'm developing a New Year greeting card and I would like to make an image appear from below after pressing the button that also starts the music.
How can I do it using jquery?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn_music .fa-play-circle").on('click', function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.fa-pause-circle').fadeIn();
    $('#myMusic')[0].play();
    $("#container").fireworks({
      sound: true, // sound effects
      opacity: 0.55,
      width: '90%',
      height: '10%'
    }).play();
    $('#champagne').hide();
    $('#champagne').slideToggle(1000);





  });

  $(".btn_music .fa-pause-circle").on('click', function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.fa-play-circle').fadeIn();
    $('#myMusic')[0].pause();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(#000, #01f);
  font: 10.5em Arial;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.stroke {
  stroke: goldenrod;
  stroke-width: 0.5px;
  stroke-dasharray: 0 250;
  stroke-opacity: 1;
  fill: none;
  animation: stroke_offset 8s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
}

@keyframes stroke_offset {
  25% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 250;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dasharray: 250 0;
    stroke-opacity: 0.75;
  }
  55% {
    stroke-dasharray: 250 0;
    stroke-opacity: 0;
  }
  70% {
    stroke-dasharray: 250 0;
    stroke-opacity: 0;
  }
  75% {
    stroke-dasharray: 250 0;
    stroke-opacity: 0.75;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 250;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }
}

.fill {
  fill: gold;
  fill-opacity: 0;
  animation: fill_offset 8s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
}

@keyframes fill_offset {
  25% {
    fill-opacity: 0;
  }
  35% {
    fill-opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
  }
  70% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
  }
  90% {
    fill-opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    fill-opacity: 0;
  }
}

#fade-text {
  font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
  font-size: 0.6em;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.music {
  position: absolute;
  top: 22%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.btn_music {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 85px;
  border: none;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  opacity: .1;
  transition: all linear .2s;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

.btn_music:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.fa-pause-circle {
  display: none;
}

#champagne {
  display: none;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 22% 43% auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <div class="music">
    <audio volume="1" id="myMusic" src="/public/music/Pepe-pepe-pepe-Disco-Samba-HQ.mp3" loop=""></audio>
    <button class="btn_music">
                        <i class="far fa-play-circle"></i>
                        <i class="far fa-pause-circle"></i>
                    </button>
  </div>
  <svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 800 600">

                     <symbol id="fade-text">
                      <text x="50%" y="30%" text-anchor="middle">Happy New Year !</text>
                      <text x="48%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle">2021</text>
                    </symbol>
                  
                    <g>
                      <use class="stroke" xlink:href="#fade-text"/>
                      <use class="fill" xlink:href="#fade-text"/>
                    </g>
                  
                </svg>
  <br/>

  <img src="public/img/cin_cin.gif" id="champagne">


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="public/js/jquery.fireworks.js"></script>

  <script src="/public/js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

With jQuery, with the play button I would like to start the music, the fireworks and view the photo while with the pause button I would like to pause the music, the fireworks and make the photo disappear.
Is it possible to do it or not?

Comment: Why not just bind the click event to the button itself and toggle the play/pause classes on just one tag?

Comment: By clicking on the button I was able to start / stop the music and start the fireworks, but I can't get the photo to appear from below and stop the fires.                                       What function can I implement to do this and how?